# Removing dates if they are not in DD/mm/yyyy format

Tags: javascript, date, format

I have a file collected daily in an integration process which has a date of birth field. The file is currently moved from a local server to a vendor SFTP. They do some magic on the data and import back into our system.

Our data may have date of birth in YYYY format if we don't know the full date but this cannot be read by the vendor.

How do I remove date of birth if data is in the format YYYY but keep if in correct format as above. (JavaScript).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Check the length?

Comment: @Teemu what about DD-mm-YYYY  or YYYY/MM/DD or ... they are all same length?

Comment: @John Who cares, YYYY and DD/MM/YYYY are the options ..? "_we don't know the full date_", then YYYY, otherwise DD/MM/YYYY, or do you think I've misunderstood the question? Though the question lacks a very important information, "_remove date of birth_", from what?

Comment: What have you tried? Where is the code?

Answer (score -1):

I believe we can use moment to check.

npm install moment

```
const moment = require("moment");
moment("10/12/2001", "DD/MM/yyyy"); <-- valid
moment("10/13/2001", "DD/MM/yyyy"); <-- invalid
```